# Conditional formatting: using row() inside indirect() inside and() doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Say I have set a value of 55 on cell B2.

If it's value is 55, the cell's background color should be green. So I created a new rule using a formula by selecting "User a formula to determine which cells to format" and set the formula to the following:

```
=B2 = 55
```

It worked, obviously. But because we don't want to hard-code the row because we are using this spreadsheet as a template in an application that generates more rows by simply copying that cell to another row, I set the formula to this one:

```
=INDIRECT( "B" & row() ) = 55
```

And because we actually want two conditions and our requirement is not as simple as that, I tried the following:

```
=AND( INDIRECT( "B" & row() ) >= 50, INDIRECT( "B" & row() ) <= 60 )
```

Which means set the background to green if the value is between 50 and 60 (inclusive). And that did not work. But the following works:

```
=AND( INDIRECT( "B" & "2" ) >= 50, INDIRECT( "B" & "2" ) <= 60 )
```

Could anyone tell me why does the latter work but the former that calls row() doesn't?

It seems row() only doesn't work if it's used with combination of AND() and INDIRECT() as demonstrated below:

```
=AND( ROW() = 2 ) -> this one works
=INDIRECT( "B" & row() ) = 55 -> this one works too
=AND( INDIRECT( "B" & row() ) ) = 55 -> doesn't work :((
```

Could someone explain this why? Is this a bug in Excel 2010? And how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `row()` at all?  I.e., don't the relative references get auto-updated when you copy to a new row?

Comment: No, because it's not copied by using a copy-paste method using the clipboard which I clearly specified in the question. The application (a program we made written in some language) copies the rows with its formatting intact but changes the values as it creates more rows. The first row acts like a template for the other rows. It's not done by opening the spreadsheet file in the Excel and manually doing the copy-paste to copy the row. Excel can't help here that's why we need to use INDIRECT and ROW functions.

Comment: @Marc, that means, if I don't use row() all the rows' conditional formatting will use hard-coded "B2" because the application simply copies the formatting "as is" and doesn't do anything special as Excel does when you do copy-paste manually.

Comment: It looks like a bug, and I reproduced it in 2013, but you can easily get rid of `AND` with `=(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())<=60)*(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())>=50)`. This version works OK.

Comment: @BrakNicku, I actually tried surrounding it with AVERAGE or MIN and it worked too but yours looks more elegant. Put it as an answer and if couple of my tests pass your answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @BrakNicku, also if you can cite a reputable reference stating that this is a known bug, it would be great.

Comment: The amended INDIRECT might work, but I cannot believe it is needed as Marc says. It seems to me that by selecting your initial range, let's say it starts in row 2, and using a CF a formula of =AND($B2>=50,$B2<=60) would work fine, and is far more elegant than INDIRECT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you faced looks like a bug, here are some forum links, where people describe exactly the same problem: [link1](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/619404-conditional-formatting-using-formula.html),[link2](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/604433-conditional-formatting-using-indirect.html).

In one of those topics you can read that if you enclose your CF formula with `ISERROR`, it returns (for unknown reason) `True`. Same formula entered in a cell works perfectly fine.

The easiest solution in your case is to replace:

```
=AND(condition1,condition2)
```

With equivalent:

```
=(condition1)*(condition2)
```

The other workaround shown in one of the linked threads is to replace:

```
INDIRECT("B" & row())
```

With its equivalent:

```
INDEX($B:$B,ROW())
```

Both solutions work fine in conditional formatting rule.