# Formula returns true, but formatting doesn't happen

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have the following data style:

[image: My data]

I need to format the columns background color in such a way that, if the header (merged cell) is found on another sheet, it should change the 3 columns color.

So, I did this formula

`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;INT(COLUMN()/3)*3));Plan2!$A:$A;0);0);TRUE)`

As you can see on the screenshot, it returns "VERDADEIRO"(True) or "FALSO"(False) when on a cell. However it doesn't work when I put it on the conditional formatting.

I want to put that formula on the Conditional Formatting (Or something like that formula) and make it work. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

*The formula was originally in Portuguese, to translate it to english, I've uploaded to google sheets, since it auto-translates, to avoid errors

Comment: What's the conditional formatting formula you're using? Just checking the cells for `VERDADEIRO` or `FALSO`?  Or are you trying to use your formula as the conditional format formula?

Comment: I am using my formula as the conditional format formula. Since it returns `VERDADEIRO`it should work(Because it will only format if it returns true, right?) but it doesn't. I fail to see what is going wrong.

Comment: What's the "Applies to Range" you're using?

Comment: Either `=$C$1` or `=$C$1:$N$1`. All fails. I tested with `=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;INT(COLUMN()/3)*3));Plan2!$A:$A;0);0);TRUE;TRUE)`, and then it formats! But it means that my formula is, somehow, returning false.

Comment: While I could also post there, I fail to see why the language of the formula would be an issue, considering I translated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in excel regarding `INDIRECT` with Conditional Formatting.

Based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930584/conditional-formatting-using-row-inside-indirect-inside-and-doesnt-work), I replaced the `INDIRECT` with an `INDEX`alternative.

The current formula is:

`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(INDEX($C$1:$ZZ$1;;INT(COLUMN()/3)*3);Plan2!$A:$A;0);0);TRUE)`